# How to set a variable for the main handlebars layout without passing it to every route?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars with nodejs and express. This is my main.handlebars file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class ="container">
            ...
            <footer>
                &copy; {{copyrightYear}} Meadowlark Travel
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So far I'm passing the copyright year to every route:

```
var date = new Date();
var copyrightYear = date.getFullYear();

app.get(
    '/',
    function( req, res) {
        res.render(
            'home',
            {
                copyrightYear: copyrightYear
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Is it possible to set the `copyrightYear` variable globally, so I don't have to pass it on to every route/view?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ExpressJS provides some kind of "global variables". They are mentioned in the docs: [app.locals](http://expressjs.com/api#app.locals). To include it in every response you could do something like this:

```
app.locals.copyright = '2014';
```

Comment: How would this be used in the theme? Is it just `{{ copyright }}`? Or `{{ locals.copyright }}`? (I'm assuming the former, but also trying to poke you to include the information, to make this as complete as possible :)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I was asking myself the same question and edited the answer with the info afterwards.

Comment: What about request level data? Like req.user.id?

Answer (score 14):

For this case, you can alternatively create a Handlebars helper. Like this:

```js
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

Handlebars.registerHelper('copyrightYear', function() {
  var year = new Date().getFullYear();

  return new Handlebars.SafeString(year);
});
```

In the templates, just use it as before:

```html
&copy; {{copyrightYear}} Meadowlark Travel
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer to the question. Thanks for this simple idea

Answer (score 6):

Using `express-handlebars` is just a little bit different:

```
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({
    defaultLayout:'main',
    helpers: {
        copyrightYear: function() {
            return new Date().getFullYear();
        },
    }
});
```