# How to display the current user in Handlebars layout when using Passport.js?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, passport.js

I can eazy return the current admin in view after use PassportJs to authenticate by this

```js
dashboard(req,res,next){          
    var CurentAdmin = req.user.adminname
    res.render('admin/dashboard',{layout:'admin',CurentAdmin})
}
```

And just call "CurentAdmin" in this view

But i want to show the current admin have logged in in a layout template. How can i do it.

This is a part of file layout "admin.handelbars"(a layout not a view)

```html
<div class="admin-detail">                         
    <p class="admin-name">{{ Current Admin must be here }}</p>
    <i class="admin-icon fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
    <div class="admin-actions">
       <div class="admin-logout">Đăng xuất</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a variable for the main handlebars layout without passing it to every route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095991/how-to-set-a-variable-for-the-main-handlebars-layout-without-passing-it-to-every)

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
res.render('admin/dashboard',{
    layout:'admin',
    CurentAdmin: req.user.adminname
});
```

In tempale:

```
<p class="admin-name">{{CurentAdmin}}</p>
```